# Show only 3 values in an array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have included given code

```
@students = "All #{section.count}#{section.values}"

output: "All 9['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']"
```

But I want  show output to be **All 9['A','B','C',...]**

Please guide me how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print first 3 elements of Array and then manipulate the String to include ellipsis. Here:

```
section.values
# => ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]

puts "#{section.values[0..2]}".sub("]",", ...]")
# ["A", "B", "C", ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#take` method too. Example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.take(2) # will give as result [1,2]
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
@students = "All #{section.count}#{(section.count > 3) ? (section.values[0..2] << '...') : section.values}"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: you are printing `["A", "B", "C", "..."]` which essentially means your 4th element is `"..."` which is incorrect.

Comment: @shivam Yes correct, didn't test the solution in irb!

Answer (score 0):

first get all records and store it on @student.
and use first() method

```
@student.first(count)
```